Curvature of a connection and Lie bracket of vector fields
Let $M$ be a manifold, $\pi:E\to M$ a vector bundle and $\nabla$ a connection on $E$. It defines a horizontal subbundle $HE$ of $TE$ such that each vector field $X$ on $M$ admits a unique horizontal lift $\tilde{X}$ on $E$. Denote by $K:TE\to E$ the connector map associated to $\nabla$ (more precisely it is the composition of the projection to $VE$ with the natural map $VE\simeq\pi^*E\to E$).
I want to prove that for any vector fields $X$ and $Y$ on $M$ and any section $s$ of $E$, $$R(X,Y)s=-K({[}\tilde{X},\tilde{Y}{]}(s))$$ where $R$ is the curvature of $\nabla$. So far, all my attempts were unsuccessful. Is there a reference where I could read the proof of this?

Have you tried working this out in coordinates? I think this may be the only  way since I don’t believe you get a global form on $E$ with values in $VE$ like you do with the principal bundle formalism. The horizontal lift should be dependent on the christoffel symbols

@Chris I tried but I don't understand how to express $K$ in local coordinates.

in local coordinates $(x^1,\dots , x^n,y^1,\dots,y^k)$, where $x^i$ are coordinates on $M$, and $y^i$ are coordinates on the model fibre, then  $K$ just takes any $M$ coordinates to zero.

I am actually struggling to make sense of what you mean by $\tilde X,\tilde Y$ and how this is an element of $TE$.

Additionally I realized my original statement was incorrect, in local coordinates, your projection must have kernel equal to the horizontal subspace, so this should also depend on christoffel symbols

@Chris By $[\tilde{X},\tilde{Y}]$ I denote the Lie Bracket of the vector fields $\tilde{X},\tilde{Y}\in\Gamma(TE)$. It is a vector field on $E$. If $s\in\Gamma(E)$ and $p\in M$, then $\tilde{X},\tilde{Y}$ is the value of this vector field at the point $s(p)\in E$.

I think your original statement is correct. Via a local trivialization of the bundle, we obtain coordinates $(x^1,\dots,x^n,y^1,\dots,y^k)$ such that the vector fields $(\partial y^1,\dots,\partial y^k)$ span the vertical subbundle at each point. The difficulty here is to understand the lifts of $X$ and $Y$.

My point is that the vertical projection can’t have kernel equal to $T_pM$ everywhere or else we would have the trivial connection.

thank you for clearing up your notation, I thought you were somehow applying $[\tilde{X},\tilde{Y}]$ to $s$ like a function which confused me. I have written up an answer which does this in local coordinates.
I will say that I think in general treating $E$ has a vector bundle associated to it's frame bundle $F(E)$, and working with the horizontal bundle on $F(E)$ determined by a connection one form (which is now globally defined) is often more convenient if you wish to avoid coordinates.

Given a connection $\nabla$, for any frame $\{e_i\}$ , we can write:
$$\nabla e_i=\xi_i^j\otimes e_j$$
where $\xi_i^j$ are local one forms on $U$. Note that the frame $\{e_i\}$ defines coordinates for $E|_U\cong U\times V$, by:
$$(y^1,\dots, y^m)=y^ie_i$$
We thus define local one forms on $U\times V$ by:
$$\theta^i=dy^i+\xi_k^iy^k$$
The horizontal subbundle is then locally given by:
$$H|_{U}=\bigcap_i\ker \theta^i$$
If $X$ is a vector field on $M$, and $\tilde{X}=W^\mu\partial_{x^\mu} +Y^j\partial_{y^j}$, then we have that $\theta^i(\tilde{X})=0$ for all $i$. Note that this implies that:
\begin{align}
Y^i+\xi^i_{\mu k}y^kW^{\mu}=0
\end{align}
In particular, we know that since $\pi_*(\tilde{X})=X$, we have that $W^\mu=X^\mu$. It follows that locally:
\begin{align}
\tilde{X}=X^\mu\partial_{x^{\mu}}-\xi^i_{\mu k}y^kX^{\mu}\partial_{y^i}
\end{align}
The vertical projection is then given in coordinates by:
$$K:Z\longmapsto \theta^i(Z)\partial_{y^i}\longmapsto \theta^i(Z)e_i$$
If $X$ and $Z$ are two vector fields on $M$, we have that:
\begin{align}
[\tilde{X},\tilde{Z}]=&[X^\mu\partial_{x^{\mu}}-\xi^i_{\mu k}y^kX^{\mu}\partial_{y^i},Z^{\nu}\partial_{x^{\nu}}-\xi^j_{\nu l}y^lZ^{\nu}\partial_{y^j}]\\
=&[X,Z]-[X^\mu\partial_{x^\mu},\xi^j_{\nu l}y^lZ^{\nu}\partial_{y^j}]-[\xi^i_{\mu k}y^kX^{\mu}\partial_{y^i},Z^\nu\partial_{x^\nu}]+[\xi^i_{\mu k}y^kX^{\mu}\partial_{y^i},\xi^j_{\nu l}y^lZ^{\nu}\partial_{y^j}]
\end{align}
For each term we have that:
\begin{align*}
        [X,Z]=&(X^\mu\partial_{x^\mu}Z^\nu)\partial_{x^{\nu}}-(Z^{\nu}\partial_{x^{\nu}}X^\mu)\partial_{x^{\mu}}\\
        -[\xi^i_{\mu k}y^kX^{\mu}\partial_{y^i},Z^\nu\partial_{x^\nu}]=&Z^\nu\left[(\partial_{x^{\nu}}\xi^i_{\mu k})
        y^kX^\mu+ \xi^i_{\mu k}y^k(\partial_{x^{\nu}} X^\mu)\right]\partial_{y^i}\\
        -[X^\mu\partial_{x^\mu},\xi^j_{\nu l}y^lZ^{\nu}\partial_{y^j}]=&-X^\mu\left[(\partial_{x^\mu}\xi^j_{\nu l})y^lZ^\nu+
        \xi^j_{\nu l}y^l(\partial_{x^\mu}Z^\nu)\right]\partial_{y^j}\\
        [\xi^i_{\mu k}y^kX^{\mu}\partial_{y^i},\xi^j_{\nu l}y^lZ^{\nu}\partial_{y^j}]=&
        \xi^i_{\mu k}\xi^j_{\nu i}y^kX^\mu Z^\nu\partial_{y^j}-\xi^j_{\nu l}\xi^i_{\mu j} y^lX^\mu Z^\nu\partial_{y^i}
        \end{align*}
Now if $s=s^me_m$ is a section, evaluating on the section is the same as replacing every $y$ term with $s$. By replacing
dummy indices, it follows that:
\begin{align*}
    K([X,Z](s))=&\xi^i_k([X,Z])s^ke_i\\
    K(-[\xi^i_{\mu k}y^kX^{\mu}\partial_{y^i},Z^\nu\partial_{x^\nu}](s))=&
    Z^\nu\left[(\partial_{x^{\nu}}\xi^i_{\mu k})s^kX^\mu+\xi^i_{\mu k}(\partial_{x^{\nu}} s^k)X^\mu + 
    \xi^i_{\mu k}s^k(\partial_{x^{\nu}} X^\mu)\right]e_i\\
    =&\left[Z(\xi^i_k(X))s^k+\xi^i_k(X)ds^k(Z)\right]e_i\\
    K(-[X^\mu\partial_{x^\mu},\xi^j_{\nu l}y^lZ^{\nu}\partial_{y^j}](s))=&-[X(\xi^i_k(Z))s^l+\xi^i_k(Z)ds^k(X)]e_i\\
    K([\xi^i_{\mu k}y^kX^{\mu}\partial_{y^i},\xi^j_{\nu l}y^lZ^{\nu}\partial_{y^j}])=&\left[\xi^i_l(Z)\xi^l_k(X)-\xi^i_l(X)\xi^l_k(Z)\right]s^ke_i\\
    =&-\left[\xi^i_j\wedge xi^l_k\right](X,Z)s^ke_i
    \end{align*}
Adding these all together we get that:
\begin{align}
        K([\tilde{X},\tilde{Z}](s))=&-\left(X(\xi^i_k(Z))-Z(\xi^i_k(X))-\xi^i_k[X,Z]+\left[\xi^i_l\wedge \xi^l_k\right](X,Z)\right)s^ke_i\\
        =&-\left(d\xi^i_k(X,Z)+\left[\xi^i_l\wedge \xi^l_k\right](X,Z)\right)s^ke_i\\
        =&-R(X,Z)^i_ks^ke_i\\
        =&-R(X,Z)s
    \end{align}
implying the claim.

Thanks! This is very neat. I did not understand that one could write $HE$ as the kernel of the $\theta_i$. I got it now.

I cannot figure out how does one write a horizontal lift using local coordinates. However, using this lecture notes I was able to reduce the proof to a simple claim (which is not treated in the notes). Here is the partial proof.
Fix a point $p\in M$. We can always find a frame of $E$ whose covariant derivatives at $p$ vanish. Hence we can assume that $\nabla_vs(p)=0$ for all $v\in T_pM$. Recall that $ds(X)=\tilde{X}(s)+\Phi(\nabla_Xs)$ where $\Phi:VE\to E$ is the map that identifies $V_eE$ with $E_{\pi(e)}$ for every $e\in E$. By assumption, $ds(X(p))=\tilde{X}(s(p))$ for every vector field $X\in\mathfrak{X}(M).$
We claim that $$\nabla_X(K(ds(Y)))(p)-\nabla_Y(K(ds(X)))(p)=d^{\pi^*\nabla}K(ds(X(p)),ds(Y(p)))$$
where on the right hand side, we see $K$ as a $1$-form on $E$ with value in $\pi^*E$ and $d^{\pi^*\nabla}:\Omega^1(E,\pi^*E)\to\Omega^2(E,\pi^*E)$ is the exterior covariant derivative associated to $\pi^*\nabla$.
Recall that $\nabla_Xs=K(ds(X))$ for any vector field $X\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$ and that $K$ vanishes on horizontal vectors. Then
\begin{align*}
    R(X,Y)s(p)&=\nabla_X\nabla_Ys(p)-\nabla_Y\nabla_Xs(p)-\nabla_{[X,Y]}s(p)\\
    &=\nabla_X(K(ds(Y)))(p)-\nabla_Y(K(ds(X)))(p)-K(ds([X,Y](p)))\\
    &=d^{\pi^*\nabla}K(ds(X(p)),ds(Y(p)))-K(\widetilde{[X,Y]}(s(p)))\\
    &=d^{\pi^*\nabla}K(\tilde{X},\tilde{Y})(s(p))\\
    &=(\pi^*\nabla)_{\tilde{X}}(K(\tilde{Y}))(s(p))-(\pi^*\nabla)_{\tilde{Y}}(K(\tilde{X}))(s(p))-K([\tilde{X},\tilde{Y}](s(p)))\\
&=-K([\tilde{X},\tilde{Y}](s(p)))
\end{align*}
which concludes the proof.
Edit: I finally found a reference with a totally different approach: Theorem 12.50 in Manifolds and differential geometry, Lee. Unfortunately, the proof relies on many previous lemmas. I would really like to know how one can prove this statement more directly.
